# Using a custom (forked) @types module

Tags: typescript

I forked [@types/stripe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/stripe) from [github.com/DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/stripe) into my own [github repo](https://github.com/reggi/types-stripe) / [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@reggi/types-stripe).

I am assuming this will not work automatically, now that it is a custom type module.

I tried this, adding `@reggi/types-stripe` to the `types` in `compilerOptions` for the `tsconfig.json`, but I still don't think the connection to the new type module is working for stripe.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "@reggi/types-stripe"
    ]
  }
}
```

(Also tried `"./node_modules/@reggi/types-stripe"`)

How do I make my typescript compiler aware of this new module `@reggi/types-stripe`?

Comment: have u installed the forked module as dependency?

Comment: Hi @seanplwong yes, i've run `yarn remove @types/stripe && yarn add @reggi/types-stripe`

Comment: it is unlikely that simply changing the types will work, tsc will look for `@reggis/types-stripe` in `typeRoots`, so you might need `typeRoots: ['./node_modules/@reggi', './node_modules/@types']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Background

Alright, so to find a solution for this we first need to understand how TypeScript finds the type definitions for a certain module. Somehow the type definitions have to be mapped to the module name. There are two possible ways this can be done that I'm aware of:

#### Using `declare module`

`d.ts` files may specify the module name like this:

```js
declare module 'stripe' {
   // types
}
```

It doesn't matter what name this file has or in which folder it is located. The module name is defined *in* the file using `declare module`. Of course TypeScript still needs to load the file though, otherwise it won't do anything.

#### Using the filename

Types in `@types` (including the official one from stripe) are resolved by their filename. That means if you import `stripe`, TypeScript will check if there is a definitions file under `node_modules/@types/stripe` and load it as type for this module.

---

### Solution

Now, let's see what this tells us about your problem. The type definitions for stripe don't include a `declare module` statement. This means simply getting TypeScript to load the file will not work.

You have multiple options:

#### 1. Use a path mapping

In `tsconfig.json` add the [`paths`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) and `baseUrl` options (`baseUrl` is required for `paths` to work):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "stripe": ["./node_modules/@reggi/types-stripe"]
    }
  }
}
```

We're telling TypeScript to look for `stripe` in a different location when resolving it.

You can also make this more dynamic for multiple packages with a wildcard:

```
"paths": {
  "*": ["./node_modules/@reggi/types/*", "*"]
}
```

Note that in this case the types would have to be located in a subfolder called `stripe` alongside subfolders for potential other packages.

#### 2. Add `declare module`

Alternatively you could modify the `index.d.ts` to include a `declare module` statement. You would basically have to wrap the whole contents of the file in it like so:

```js
declare module 'stripe' {
    class Stripe {
        DEFAULT_HOST: string;
        DEFAULT_PORT: string;
    // ...
}
```

Note that TypeScript will complain about the two `declare` keywords (`declare class Stripe` and `declare namespace Stripe`) in the existing type definitions. Remove those two `declare` keywords, they are not needed anymore.

Finally we have to insure that `d.ts` file is loaded. The easiest way is to add it to the `include` option in `tsconfig.json`

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "include": [
    "./node_modules/@reggi/types-stripe/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

---

> **Note:** You don't necessarily have to use a npm package for this if you don't want to. To TypeScript it doesn't matter where the files come from as long as you specify the path in `typeRoots` / `include` correctly.

Comment: Hey, I just tired this an it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I think that's because TypeScript tries to find the types based on the name of the module. So because it's called `stripe` it is going to look for a `stripe` folder under each `typeRoot`. I'll update the answer if I find something that'll work better for your case.

Comment: Okay I've updated my answer. Please let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: OK, I would like to not use `declare module` so I have a folder named `stripe` with an `index.d.ts` file in it. I am not getting any typing on the `stripe` module. If I call `/// <reference types="stripe" />` from any local `.d.ts` file it does link to this new `stripe/index.d.ts` file but the module call does not. Any ideas?

Comment: Works with `declare module 'stripe'` but for some reason I can't it to work with a folder named `stripe`.

Comment: Okay, just to check: Did you add the path to `typesRoots`? Is `index.d.ts` located under: `./node_modules/@reggi/types-stripe/stripe/index.d.ts`? Did you remove `declare module` from the file?

Comment: I have `typeRoots` as `[ "./node_modules/@types", "./src/types-package" ]` and `include` as `[ "./src/**/*" ]` and the package at `./src/types-package/stripe/index.d.ts` and without `declare module`.

Comment: Hmm... and the error is something along the lines of `Cannot find module 'stripe'`? Or do you get something else?

Comment: No errors in the `tsconfig.json` file. Or during execution of a file importing `stripe`.

Comment: When I hover over a specific stripe type with @types/stripe it will give me the type, with @types/stripe removed I get any. I'm trying to have a local typeRoot with stripe to take it's place. When I add the local root hover over the type it says "any" so the types for the module aren't loaded.

Comment: Okay I think I got it. `typeRoots` is actually the wrong option here. As [this comment on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22217#issuecomment-369783776) points out, it is only used to load global definitions. Not those of individual modules. However we can use the `paths` option to make it work. Please take a look at the updated answer (Solution #1 - Use a path mapping)

Comment: You're most welcome. I also learned something new on the way, which is always great :)

Comment: finally a good explanation that works. Went through dozen old/wrong suggestions and finally this one works and also clears out why it works. Thx man!

Answer (score 0):

@lukasgeiter's answer is close. Simply mentioning your packages in `types` is not likely to work, because it is not living under the `@types` space. You might need to alter `typeRoots` to include your package's parent.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@reggi",
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    // you might also need this
    "types": ["types-stripe", "some-other-types"]
  }
}
```

You may also try to include the package if the above doesn't work

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "include": [
    "./node_modules/@reggi/types-stripe"
  ]
}
```